# How to install a binary on Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am running a Spring Boot Web App on Azure App Service. The application has a dependency on a binary (ffprobe in my case) and needs that binary to be present on the system. Is there a way to install the dependent binaries?

Comment: Just copy it somewhere under `d:\home\site` and reference it as `%HOME%\site\ffprobe.exe`. Better yet make it part of your source control so you can control which version of `ffprobe` goes with what release. If you're deploying through Kudu, there's a PostDeployment action as well, see https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1934

Answer (score 0):

You can use "kudu" in your Azure app service(go to your app service and click "Advance Tools" --> "Go" --> "Debug console" --> "CMD" --> "site" --> "wwwroot" --> new a folder named "bin" and drag your binary to this folder. Then you can use it by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233915/how-to-run-a-exe-in-an-azure-app-service) post.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to install a product like running an msi, registering a COM component or installing something in the GAC, then one possibility is to use Windows Containers.

Here you can follow the quickstart to run a Windows Container in App Service:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-windows-container